# Word that means "something that can be abbreviated"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

The two answers that spring to mind are "**abbreviable**" and "**abbreviatable**," however neither of them feel correct. Searching the Internet has yielded no conclusive results - dictionaries seem to contain no entries for this, and people seem to restructure their sentence to avoid this problem. Trying to find usage of the two candidates I thought of is just as inconclusive, with no definitions or accepted standard.

Is there a correct answer? A single word is preferable.

An example in English would be "The phrase 'I don't know' is abbreviable to 'IDK'."

The original intended usage is for a Python project. Using more than one word for this would be too verbose.

```
class AbbreviatableIdentifier:
    ...
```

Comment: The first question I've ever agreed has shown reasonable signs of research as being nil. Worth an upvote. 'Wiktionary' tends to be a bit quicker on the uptake when it comes to new words than some more ... er ... traditional dictionaries, so these words are probably not all that common.

Comment: Surely anything called `AbbreviatableIdentifier` could more sensibly be called `Identifier` (with a little effort almost any identifier can be abbreviated), and the abbreviation would be called `AbbreviatedIdentifier`.  In some cases the two attributes of the same thing might be the same but so what ?  The rarity of occurrence of the words *abbreviable* and *abbreviatable* perhaps hints that the concept is not used very much, and that it isn't useful very often.

Comment: How about "abr'v'able"?

Answer (score 1):

The word "abbreviable" is synonymous with "abbreviateable", so your example is correct.

[From Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abbreviable):

> abbreviable (adjective): Able to be abbreviated.

That said, you don't have to use full words while programming.  A function name like "AbbrID" would have enough context clues to key in a reader to what the function does without being too verbose to type each time you need it.

Comment: Abbreviating it to "abbr" is exactly the workaround I was using. In the context of its actual usage it's a little more ambiguous (is it referring to something that *is* an abbreviation, or something that *could* be abbreviated?), but it's a good enough solution.